# Can I have 5 panels in a row

Tags: java, jpanel, border-layout

Is it possible to have 5 `JPanels` in a row in a single Frame? Heres my code you may get a better understanding of the question:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(mainOrderInfo, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(meatPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(cheesePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(ingrediantsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(addonsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

When the code is ran all I get are the `meatPanel`, `cheesePanel`, and `ingrediantsPanel`. I would like the `mainOrderInfo` to be to the left of the `meatPanel` and the `addonsPanel` to the right of the `ingredientsPanel`. I feel as though its simple a matter of code or ordering of code that I am not aware of.

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout`, see [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you all for the answers this will work perfect and now I have a bunch of different options to try. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @poke for editing the post its a lot more to the point now. In the future I will try to make sure the different pieces of code in my description match the code block that is a lot easier to identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `GridLayout`

See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more details

[image: GridLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
            add(createPanel(Color.WHITE));
            add(createPanel(Color.BLACK));
            add(createPanel(Color.RED));
            add(createPanel(Color.GREEN));
            add(createPanel(Color.BLUE));
        }

        protected JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(50, 50);
                }
            };
            panel.setBackground(color);
            return panel;
        }

    }

}
```

## `GridBagLayout`

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(createPanel(Color.WHITE), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createPanel(Color.BLACK), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createPanel(Color.RED), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createPanel(Color.GREEN), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(createPanel(Color.BLUE), gbc);
        }

        protected JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(50, 50);
                }
            };
            panel.setBackground(color);
            return panel;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have many panels in a row with a layout [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

> The Swing packages include a general purpose layout manager named
>   BoxLayout. BoxLayout either stacks its components on top of each other
>   or **places them in a row —** your choice. You might think of it as a
>   version of FlowLayout, but with greater functionality.

For your panels (ingrediantsPanel, addonsPanel) put the panels desired to the `Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);` and add this [box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html%20Box) to EAST. The panels will be laid out along x axis.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));

```
add(mainOrderInfo);

add(meatPanel);

add(cheesePanel);

add(ingrediantsPanel);

add(addonsPanel;
```